# Force eviction of Hazelcast IMap entries at TTL

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I came across a problem where Hazelcast's map is evicting entries at a significant delay from configured TTL. Found a solution to set the following properties to force eviction at TTL here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8894. The properties can be reset as:

Config config = new Config();
config.setProperty("hazelcast.internal.map.expiration.task.period.seconds", "1");
config.setProperty("hazelcast.internal.map.expiration.cleanup.percentage", "100");
config.setProperty("hazelcast.internal.map.expiration.cleanup.operation.count", "271");

The problem now is that these properties apply to the entire hazelcast instance. Is anyone aware if this can be set for only a single map in the instance? MapConfig as such does not have a setProperty() method.

P.S: the above properties work only for hazelcast 3.8 and above.

Comment: what do you mean by Hazelcast evicting after significant delay? How do you measure this delay?

Comment: If the map TTL is 20s and I have 100 entries in my map added simultaneously  with milliseconds difference, I see the EntryEvictedListener's entryEvicted()  getting called in batches of 20s, 25s, 30s and 35s.

Comment: That’s because the periodic eviction runs every 5 seconds that removes entries that have expired. If you do a map.get on expired entries, you will see eviction happening on that get call.

Comment: Entries, even when expired, remain in the cluster until they are evicted in the periodic eviction or on a map.get invocation.

Comment: I discovered an EntryExpiredListener and its entryExpired() also behaves the same as ExtryEvictedListener's entryEvicted(). I expected entryExpired() to be called after TTLs. Could you clarify why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the entry is not removed yet, expired entries will be unreachable and will be sweeped eventually either by the periodic cleanup process or when user tries to reach that entry. With those properties you can define the behavior of the cleanup process.

About your second question; yes, those properties are cluster level, they can't be applied per map basis.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. The problem is that I have some logic in the eviction listener which must be called after TTLs without much delay. Since changing these properties might have a performance hit, I wanted to apply them only for that single map.

Comment: Maybe opening a [github issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/) for this requirement would help to start a discussion about this requirement.